# With Cucimber-jvm 1.2.5, I still get "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Not a Map or List type: class java.lang.String""

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured

I still get “cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Not a Map or List type: class java.lang.String”" with Cucimber-jvm 1.2.5.

This is the POM.XML that shows the cucumber, rest assured, pico-container dependencies. I have tried 1.2.3 , 1.2.4, 1.2.5 versions and still the same. The problem is that I keep moving from one error to another, but if I use courgette-jvm the issues disappear. But then again for some reasons that library is not able to get to my feature files.

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>`enter code here`
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.4</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Here is one of the Step lambda methods that is using a data-table that its complaining about:

```
Given("^The Header is set to the following$", (DataTable headerDataTable) -> {

            Map<String, String> headerData = headerDataTable.asMap(String.class, String.class);

            Set<String> keys = headerData.keySet();

            for (String key : keys) {

                buildHeaders.addToHeaderMap(key, headerData.get(key));

            }

        });
```

Here is the Exception:

@scenario_404
  Scenario: Issue a post with bad credentials and verify response code 404                                                # SocialPost.feature:5
    Given The Header is set to the following                                                                              # SocialPostSteps.java:44
    And The Path is set to following with the account id "123" and the "post" text                                        # SocialPostSteps.java:58
      cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Not a Map or List type: class java.lang.String
        at cucumber.runtime.table.TableConverter.convert(TableConverter.java:75)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.tableArgument(StepDefinitionMatch.java:95)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.transformedArgs(StepDefinitionMatch.java:74)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:55)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:158)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to use proper formatting and describe your issue in more detail.

Comment: Can u add the step and datatable?  Instead of passing DataTable as argument type mention Map<String, String> in the step definition.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, and it did not work either. I had to revert to courgette-jvm and the complaining subsided. I am guessing that the changing back and forth of the pom somehow corrupted the M2 repo. Is there a way to start fresh everytime I am doing changes to the pom like do I do a mvn clean install everytime the pom is changed?